# How to execute next batch windows command if previous execution fails?

Tags: windows, testing, jenkins, batch-processing

I am trying to execute multiple windows batch commands in jenkins one after the other. The problem is that if any the of the project/build fails, it never gonna execute next windows batch commands.

My question is How to execute next windows batch command if previous execution fails?

Help me with this regard.

Comment: Tried with exit /b 0... but it didnt work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say *"multiple windows batch commands"*, do you mean:

- Multiple **Execute Windows Batch Command** build steps
- Or multiple **lines** of commands within a **single build step**?

If configuring **multiple build steps**, you just need to make sure that the last command of the build step does not return anything other than `0`. You can do this by adding **either** of the following as the very last statement in your build step:

- either `exit /b 0`
- or `echo "All done"`

As for multiple lines within the same build step, default implementation of Execute Windows Batch Command does not break if one line/statement fails (which is different from default Execute Shell implementation). As long as the very last statement returns `0`, the build step will not fail, and any lines failing in between does not matter.

Once again, you can reference to the above list to make sure that the last line always returns `0`

Comment: :I mean "Multiple Execute Windows Batch Command build steps". exit /b 0 didn't work out. Haven't yet tried with echo "All done". As of now I'm making use of upstream and down stream. But figuring out why it fails to execute next command when previous build fails. Thanks for ur info!!

Answer (score 0):

Re *"if any the of the project/build fails"*

Do you mean "if any of the batch commands fails"?

---

See [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin).

In your job config scroll down to:

**Build**

---

[ For each command that can fail **Add build step** at the bottom of this **Build** section ]

***Conditional step (single)***

*Run?* | *Not*

*!* | *Execute Windows batch commands*

*Commands* | `... your commands ...`

[ Click **Advanced...** ]

*On evaluation failure* | *Fail the build*

*Builder* | *Set the build result*

*Result* | *Success*

---

Or add just one ***Conditional step (single)*** section and write all of your commands into:

*Commands* | `... your commands ...`

---

Or maybe ***Conditional step (multiple)*** is the way to go for you. I haven't used this so far, so I'm not much of a help there.

Comment: @Gen Broser : Haven't tried with conditional Build step. will try out. Thanks for ur info.

Comment: @louis : Looks like gen broeser solution is the working one. is there any reason for why you accepted the another solution?